# Change the value of an object inside an Observable of sequence using RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have an observable sequence which represent my displayed sessions as follow :

```swift
 private let displayedSessions =
 PublishSubject<[ProgramDaySessionsModels.ViewModels.Session]>()
```

And here is my ViewModel:

```swift
struct ViewModels {

        struct Session{
            let id : Int?
            let title : String?
            let location : String?
            var isAddedToCalendar : Bool?
            var isAddedToFavorite : Bool?
            let time : String?
        }
    }
```

The displayed sessions is being binded to a table view:

```swift
func setupCellBinding(){
    displayedSessions
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to:
            tableView
                .rx
                .items(cellIdentifier:
                    R.reuseIdentifier.programDaySessionCell.identifier,
                       cellType: ProgramDaySessionCell.self)
        ){
            ( row, element, cell ) in

            cell.setup(withViewModel: element)
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Now after i call the setup method in the cell, i want to subscribe to an image tap inside my cell, regardless what is the subscription logic will be ....

I want after that to update my displayed viewModel , for example i want to change the property `isAddedToCalendar` to false/true when the subscription logic end...

**My question is , How to update or change a value stored in the `Subject` *without calling* `onNext` operator**

Answer (score 3):

ReactiveX is a *functional* paradigm. You don't "change the property," rather you emit a new property.

You could get close to doing what you want by having your initial array be an Observable of Observables `Observable<[Observable<Session>]>`. Then you can push a new session through one element without pushing the entire array. Fair warning though, this can quickly become a management nightmare.

---

Better, I think would be to have an `Observable<[Int]>` which contains session IDs and is used to populate the tableView and a separate `Observable<[Int: Observable<Session>]>` for referring to the values in each cell.

Each cell would get an ID from the first observable, and use that ID to find and subscribe to it's Session in the second. Updating an observable in the dictionary would not cause the entire table view to reload.

It's still kind of hard to manage. Maybe make the dictionary `Observable<[Int: Session]>` instead, make your Sessions Equatable, and use `distintUntilChanged()` to avoid reloading a cell unless something has actually changed in that particular session.

Also, see my answer here: [RxSwift : manage object updates in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332664/rxswift-manage-object-updates-in-the-app/52336838#52336838)

Comment: Thx, @Daniel, as you have said it's still kind of hard to manage, but it might solve the problem of updating an object, also without reloading the tableView or the cell.I will try it! thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

This is a very weird misconception people using Rx have, so It's important to highlight:

`Subject`s, and `Observable`s in general **do NOT have a value**, since an Observable is a **stream of values** and doesn't represent a single value.

Adding a value onto a Subject is done using `onNext` (or `.on(.next...)`) according to the ReactiveX standards.

The fact you think the value should be separated from the `onNext` events makes it seem to me that you need to go back to basics and read some of the Rx/ReactiveX/RxSwift documentation to understand the basic concepts of Observable streams.

Good luck!